# Impute missing data

Tags: r, integer, missing-data, r-factor

I have the following dataset:

```
> str(train)
'data.frame':   4619 obs. of  110 variables:
 $ UserID         : int  1 2 5 6 7 8 9 11 12 13 ...
 $ YOB            : int  1938 1985 1963 1997 1996 1991 1995 1983 1984 1997 ...
 $ Gender         : Factor w/ 3 levels "","Female","Male": 3 2 3 3 3 2 3 3 2 2 ...
 $ Income         : Factor w/ 7 levels "","$100,001 - $150,000",..: 1 3 6 5 4 7 5 2 4 6 ...
 $ HouseholdStatus: Factor w/ 7 levels "","Domestic Partners (no kids)",..: 5 6 5 6 6 6 6 5 5 6 ...
 $ EducationLevel : Factor w/ 8 levels "","Associate's Degree",..: 1 8 1 7 4 5 4 3 7 4 ...
 $ Party          : Factor w/ 6 levels "","Democrat",..: 3 2 1 6 1 1 6 3 6 2 ...
 $ Happy          : int  1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 ...
 $ Q124742        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","No","Yes": 2 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 2 1 ...
 $ Q124122        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","No","Yes": 1 3 3 3 2 3 1 3 3 1 ...
 $ Q123464        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","No","Yes": 2 2 2 3 2 2 1 2 2 1 ...
 $ Q123621        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","No","Yes": 2 3 3 2 2 1 1 3 2 1 ...
 $ Q122769        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","No","Yes": 2 2 2 1 3 1 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ Q122770        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","No","Yes": 3 2 2 3 3 1 1 2 3 3 ...
 $ Q122771        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","Private","Public": 3 3 2 2 3 3 1 3 3 3 ...
 $ Q122120        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","No","Yes": 2 2 2 2 2 3 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ Q121699        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","No","Yes": 3 3 3 2 2 3 2 3 3 2 ...
 $ Q121700        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","No","Yes": 2 3 2 2 3 3 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Q120978        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","No","Yes": 1 3 2 3 3 2 2 3 3 3 ...
 $ Q121011        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","No","Yes": 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 2 3 2 ...
 $ Q120379        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","No","Yes": 2 3 3 2 3 3 2 2 2 3 ...
 $ Q120650        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","No","Yes": 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ Q120472        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","Art","Science": 1 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 2 3 ...
 $ Q120194        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","Study first",..: 3 2 3 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ Q120012        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","No","Yes": 2 3 3 1 2 3 2 2 3 3 ...
 $ Q120014        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","No","Yes": 2 3 2 3 3 1 3 3 2 3 ...
 $ Q119334        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","No","Yes": 1 3 2 2 2 3 2 3 2 2 ...
 $ Q119851        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","No","Yes": 3 2 2 3 2 2 3 2 2 3 ...
 $ Q119650        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","Giving","Receiving": 1 2 2 3 2 1 2 2 2 3 ...
 $ Q118892        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","No","Yes": 3 3 3 2 3 2 1 3 2 2 ...
 $ Q118117        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","No","Yes": 3 2 2 3 3 3 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ Q118232        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","Idealist",..: 2 2 3 3 3 1 1 2 2 3 ...
 $ Q118233        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","No","Yes": 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 3 2 ...
 $ Q118237        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","No","Yes": 2 3 3 3 2 2 1 2 3 2 ...
 $ Q117186        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","Cool headed",..: 1 2 2 2 1 3 1 2 3 1 ...
 $ Q117193        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","Odd hours",..: 1 2 3 2 3 3 1 3 3 3 ...
 $ Q116797        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","No","Yes": 3 3 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 ...
 $ Q116881        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","Happy","Right": 2 2 3 3 2 2 1 2 2 1 ...
 $ Q116953        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","No","Yes": 3 3 3 3 1 3 3 3 3 1 ...
 $ Q116601        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","No","Yes": 3 3 3 2 3 3 1 3 3 1 ...
 $ Q116441        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","No","Yes": 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 ...
 $ Q116448        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","No","Yes": 2 3 3 3 2 2 1 2 3 1 ...
 $ Q116197        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","A.M.","P.M.": 3 2 2 2 2 3 1 2 3 1 ...
 $ Q115602        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","No","Yes": 3 3 3 3 3 2 1 3 2 1 ...
 $ Q115777        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","End","Start": 3 2 3 3 3 3 1 3 2 1 ...
 $ Q115610        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","No","Yes": 3 3 3 3 3 1 1 3 2 1 ...
 $ Q115611        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","No","Yes": 2 2 3 3 2 2 1 2 2 1 ...
 $ Q115899        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","Circumstances",..: 2 3 3 2 2 3 1 2 3 1 ...
 $ Q115390        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","No","Yes": 3 2 2 2 1 2 3 3 2 1 ...
 $ Q114961        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","No","Yes": 3 3 2 3 2 3 2 2 3 1 ...
 $ Q114748        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","No","Yes": 3 2 2 2 3 3 3 2 3 1 ...
 $ Q115195        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","No","Yes": 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 1 ...
 $ Q114517        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","No","Yes": 2 3 2 3 2 2 2 2 3 1 ...
 $ Q114386        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","Mysterious",..: 1 3 3 2 2 3 3 3 3 1 ...
 $ Q113992        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","No","Yes": 3 1 3 2 2 2 2 2 3 1 ...
 $ Q114152        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","No","Yes": 3 2 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 1 ...
 $ Q113583        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","Talk","Tunes": 2 3 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 1 ...
 $ Q113584        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","People","Technology": 3 2 2 3 2 1 3 2 2 1 ...
 $ Q113181        : Factor w/ 3 levels "","No","Yes": 2 3 3 3 2 3 3 2 2 1 ...
[list output truncated]
```

As you can see, I have 110 variables. I am trying to build a predictive model to predict happiness using these variables. If I leave them in factor form (CART models, randomForest etc. struggle) so I'm trying to convert these into vectorised or numeric type (to make the algorithm's life a bit easier)...

Currently I am doing it one by one e.g.:

```
> table(train_new$Q117193)

                    Odd hours Standard hours 
          1410           1299           1910 
> train_new$Q117193 = as.integer(train_new$Q117193)
> table(train_new$Q117193)

   1    2    3 
1410 1299 1910
```

You can notice that almost all the factor variables have missing values denoted by "".
I have converted this dataset to numeric using:

```
train_numeric$Gender = as.integer(train_numeric$Gender)
train_numeric[,grep(pattern="^Q1",colnames(train_numeric))] = lapply(train_numeric[,grep(pattern="^Q1",colnames(train_numeric))],as.integer)
```

I am using the mice package to impute this dataset... I am lost to be honest. Any ideas how I could fill these missing values please?

Comment: what functions from mice have you tried

Comment: I tried this: imputed = mice(complete(train)) but gives an error

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are converting `factor` variables (like Gender) into `numeric` format and to my knowledge that is not possible in this case because they contain strings, so you could only convert them to `character` I believe.

To replace all missing values ("") with `NA`s in your data frame `train` you could do something like

```
train[train == ""] <- NA
```

Comment: OK, thanks but when you convert it to chr and replace "" with NA. How can you fill these NA's now? I tried this: **imputed = mice(complete(train))** but it gives an error "Error in complete(train) : Input data must have class 'mids'."

Comment: I'm not sure but have you tried the following: convert "" to NAs (as above), keep the variables as factors and then `imp <- mice(train, m=1, maxit=2)` and `train_imp <- complete(imp, 1)` ?

Comment: I tried it but it gives an error that too many weights... I been trying to increase the weights but not sure how to do it. I think because I have almost 111 variables this is causing some issues when trying to fill in the NAs

Comment: if you run `dput(train)` or `dput(head(train))` and paste the output in your question, it would be easier to reproduce the error. you probably dont need to include all the variables, but only a "representative" subset of them

Comment: Sorted out using page 17 at http://www.stefvanbuuren.nl/publications/MICE%20in%20R%20-%20Draft.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can correct this issue while importing your file for ex. I am assuming you imported csv file so code for that woudl be

dataset<-read.csv(file="file location",sep=",",header=True,na.**strings = c("","NA"))**

it will replace your blank with NA in categorical variable